# My wind shield wiper is not working

Tags: windshield-wipers

My daughter has a 2009 Chrysler Sebring. The entire arm where you turn off and on your windshield wipers inside the car has been broken off......what in the world is the actual part that i need to look for to replace this and get her wipers going again/??

Comment: Did any wires break in the process?

Answer (score 4):

on rockauto.com - Wiper / Washer Switch

lets see if this link works.  If not, you can follow it on   https://www.rockauto.com

[Chrysler - 2009 - Sebring - 3.5L - Electrical-Switch & Relay - Wiper / Washer Switch](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/chrysler,2009,sebring,3.5l+v6,1443588,electrical-switch+&+relay,wiper+/+washer+switch,4856)

Comment: [This](http://www.rockauto.com/en/parts/oe+pro,SM153,turn+signal+switch,4832) might work better. (Actually, maybe not.)